# Angular highlight & dehighlight dynamic html using filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to write a set of filters to highlight and then dehighlight dynamically generated html:

Highlight filter:

```
app.filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (str, termsToHighlight) {
        // Sort terms by length
        termsToHighlight.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.length - a.length;
        });
        var regex = new RegExp('(' + termsToHighlight.join('|') + ')', 'g');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(str.toString().replace(regex, '<span class="highlightedSpan" style="background-color: yellow; ' +
            'font-weight: bold;">$&</span>'));
    };
});
```

Dehighlight:

```
app.filter('dehighlight', function ($sce) {
    return function (str) {

        var obj = $($.parseHTML(str));

        obj = obj.find('.highlightedSpan').replaceWith(function () { return this.innerHTML; });

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(obj.html());
    };
});
```

I'm trying to strip away the span tag and leave the original text, but I'm not sure if it's working or what to return.  Str is the html string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is Angular2 or later?

Comment: @Gunter Angular 1.6

Comment: `angularjs` is the correct tag for AngularJS 1.x. The `angular` tag is for Angular 2+ only. Using the correct tags increases chances to get a good answer.

Comment: How are you applying this filter? What's the actual problem? Is the text highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness sake, I got it in the end, the find function was misbehaving from my POV.

Final solution for dehighlighting:

```
app.filter('dehighlight', function () {
    return function (str) {
        var obj = $('<div/>').append(str);

        obj.find('span.highlightedSpan').replaceWith(function () { return this.innerHTML; });

        return obj.html().toString();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

We found marking terms with Angular to be a non-trivial task and ended up using an outside library (Mark.js). Manipulating the html directly like that can break angular's scoping and create other issues. If each possible term is in it's own little html tag, then you can use a filter on each one to test against a shared list of terms (either passed in or as part of a service), just remember that the "filter" is finicky about what changing inputs will fire a dirty-check and re-evaluate.

Comment: Interesting, this looks like it'll work, but I need to do it my way because I'm going to re-use the filters to do linking/delinking of the found matches later.  Namely I need to control what I inject / strip, which the library abstracts out.

Comment: You may have more luck using a directive with transclusion then. They are pretty tricky, but allow a lot more direct html manipulation.